# Adding a checkbox inside my asp.net mvc core will show it as disabled

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i have the following model class:-

```
 public class ContactinfoCreate
    {
        public ContactInfo ContactInfo { get; set; }
        public string CustomCheck { get; set; }
    }
```

and inside my asp.net mvc core i added the following inside my view:-

```
@model LandingPageFinal3.ViewModels.ContactinfoCreate

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="CustomCheck" name="CustomCheck">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">By submitting the N....</label>
</div>
```

but the generated checkbox will be UN-clickable... can anyone advice?

Comment: Maybe thats becasue of "custom-control-input" class you've added. remove it and have a try

Comment: @MohammadBarbast this is a built-in class that comes with bootstrap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"for" is case sensitive and input id is : "CustomCheck"

try:

```
<label class="custom-control-label" for="CustomCheck">By submitting the N....</label>
```